# Get connection string in console application

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I've created an Console application project then add new App.conf file into my project. In my configuration file, I copied connection string that I've created by adding entity framework as below:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBModel.csdl|res://*/DBModel.ssdl|res://*/DBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=MY-LAPTOP;Initial Catalog=TestDB;User ID=test;Password=123123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

On the program.cs I want to using ConfigurationManager class to retain the connection string but always raise me errors.

```
String connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
```

Please suggest me solutions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your connection string is called `DBEntities`

Use this line in your code instead:

```
String connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBEntities"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 12):

This is only a guess since you didn't include the actual exception in your question:

Add a reference to `System.Configuration` to your project.

Comment: I've fixed my problems.In my solution has many projects. Basically, on deployment project I copied the connection string section to web.conf or app.conf then I can read the connection string. Thanks so much for your response.

Answer (score 4):

Also, your name-attribute's value is `DBEntities`, but you are trying to access `ApplicationServices` in your code.