# .netCoreAPP console Application and SQL Connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have recently been looking at the new framework V1.0 on .NetCoreApp. I cant figure out how I can use the Json to make the connection. I cant figure out how I would do the Connection String to Database. Every example online is based on Web application which contains Startup Class as well as appsetting , but in my solution I can only see project.json and global.json, no configuration anywhere. I am making a console Application

Comment: Do you need to manually add a config file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014227/get-connection-string-in-console-application

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid is that how we do in .netCore now? I thought we have to use Json or some new way of doing this. There is no App.config

Comment: I'm well out of the programming scene now. I read this https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html which explains how to use EF for your database access layer. You could follow that and simply search through all the auto created config files to see where it has decided to put your connection string. I guess you must have some code somewhere that references some kind of configuration file (wrapped up in half a dozen classes no doubt)